# How to update Kendo grid aggregates without refreshing

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am working on a kendo grid with remote data, and currently when updating my grid, I use the dataItem.set() method to manually sync the grid with the data.  This works fine, but unfortunately the aggregates in the footer are not refreshed.  They refresh only when calling dataSource.fetch(), which hangs up the application for about 10 seconds.  The users however, would like more excel-like responsiveness where every change they make is immediately reflected in the total, but also persisted to the database.  Is this possible using the kendo api?  Or do I have to do this manually with jQuery?

**Edit**:  doesn't look like there's a built-in way so I fixed manually w/ jQuery.

**Edit 2**:  Here's the code I used, generalized a bit and taking out some application specific quirks.

**Kendo Grid Configuration:**

```
$(gridId).kendoGrid({
    columns: [
        {
            field: fieldToUpdate,
            editor: customEditor,
            //add 'data-field' attribute to footer/group footer
            footerAttributes: { 'data-field': fieldToUpdate },
            groupFooterAttributes: { 'data-field': fieldToUpdate }
        },
        //other fields...
    ],
    //other config...
});
```

**Custom Editor:**

```
function customEditor(data) {
    //store original and new value
    //append textbox
    //call custom update passing td and data w/ original/new values
}
```

**Find Affected Aggregate Cells:**

```
//Gets all affected aggregate cells after an update
function getTotalsCells($container, updatedField) {
    var groups = $('#grid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.group(),
        $totals = $('.k-footer-template>td[data-field="' + updatedField + '"]'),
        $row = $container.parent('tr');
    for (var i = 0; i < groups.length; i++) {
        var $groupTotal = $row.nextAll('.k-group-footer')
                              .eq(i)
                              .find('[data-field="..."]');
        $totals = $totals.add($groupTotal);
    }
    return $totals;
}
```

**Update Totals**

```
$.fn.updateTotal = function (delta) {
    this.each(function () {
        var $container = $(this);
        var origTotal = parseFloat($container.text() || 0);
        var total = origTotal + delta;
        $container.text(total);
    });
};
```

**Custom Update:**

```
function updateGrid($container, data) {
    var difference, field;
    //get difference and updatedField
    var $totals = getTotalsCells($container);
    $totals.updateTotal(difference);
}
```

I feel like there must be a better way to do this, but the aggregate model doesn't seem to update.

Comment: Do you have an example of how you fixed it manually with jQuery?

Comment: Edited my question with example code.

Comment: Thanks for the example. I went about it a bit differently. See my answer.

Comment: The aggregate is on an observable collection, isn't it?  It strikes me as peculiar that one needs to manually update an aggregate on something that's observable.  What's the point in having it be observable if it doesn't update the things that depend on it?

Answer (score 3):

My solution was to define a function that manually calculates the results and call this from within the footer template. Whenever the grid is refreshed the footer is also updated.

Client Template: `#: sumDebits() #`

```
function sumDebits() {
    var $grid = $('#GridId');
    var kendo = $grid.data().kendoGrid;
    var data = kendo.dataSource.data();
    var total = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var debit = parseFloat(data[i].Form.debit);

        if (debit == NaN) {
            debit = 0;
        }

        total = total + debit;
    }

    return total;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had almost similar problem. I had a KendoGrid which i needed to refresh the row only (update HTML and Data) and update the groupFooterTemplateand and the footerTemplate after a modal close (which it had the edit cells i needed to update to the grid). I had  "@progress/kendo-ui": "^2019.2.626". I know that is uses set but in this version set updates everything.

Bellow is the Code where you update groupFooterTemplateand ,footerTemplate , Html(row) and also excel is updated withoute Total Refresh of the Grid.

```
let grid = $('#grid').getKendoGrid(); // Kendo Grid
let dataItem = grid.dataItem(tr); // tr: JQuery (selected Row)
let index= grid.items().index(grid.select()); // or the selected Row

dataItem = data.length > 0 && data.length === 1 ? data : dataItem; // data is the new item with the same properties as the item datasource of the Grid. You can update all properties like below or just set one property.
dataItem.dirty = true;
let rowItem = grid.dataSource.at(index);
for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(dataItem )) {
    rowItem.set(key, value); //

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var grid = $("#gridName").data('kendoGrid'); 
var aggregateSum = grid.dataSource._aggregateResult;
//below code give you current aggregate value. 
var sum = aggregateSum.<your_aggregate_columnname_here>.sum; 
//assuming my Grid Column name is 'Amount' 
var sum = aggregateSum.Amount.sum;
```

To change the aggregate value without refreshing page or without fetching the `datasource`, follow below steps

```
// Set the current aggregate value to 0
aggregateSum.<your_aggregate_columnname_here>.sum = 0; 
//  i.e. aggregateSum.Amount.sum = 0;

// Loop trough Grid data row by row
var gridData = grid.dataSource.data();
for (var i = 0; i < gridData.length; i++) {
    var dataRow = gridData[i];
   // to set the aggregate sum value
   aggregateSum.Amount.sum += value;
   // to set the cell value for that particular row
   dataRow.set(ColumnName, value);
}
```

Note : Make Sure Call the `Set()` function in the end after updating the aggregate sum. If you will call Set function before setting aggregate sum, you will not be able to see the last iteration changes, as the changes will only reflect after `set()` function will get executed